# Angular 4 image selector/picker

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I'm looking for a lib or component to select a image in angular 4.
I just want a simple way to upload a profile image to my app.
I found some libs but they are outdated.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The only library I know of that provides `upload` is PrimeNG. Try it out:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload